# How do you pull WEEKLY historical data from yahoo finance?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, yahoo-finance

```
import datetime   
import pandas.io.data

sp  =  pd.io.data.get_data_yahoo('^IXIC',start = datetime.datetime(1972, 1, 3),
                       end = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 3))
```

I have used the above example, but that just pulls DAILY data into a dataframe when I would like to pull **weekly**.  It doesn't seem like `get_data_yahoo` has a parameter where you can select perhaps from daily, weekly or monthly like the options made available on yahoo itself.  Any other packages or ideas that you know of that might be able to facilitate this?

Comment: Why do you need to have the data come through weekly?  If you have it by day shouldn't you be able to do the appropriate aggregation.

Could you provide some insight into what the end result should be?  May help drive more appropriate suggestions.

Comment: So if you take a look at this link: http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=%5EGSPC&a=00&b=3&c=1950&d=11&e=14&f=2013&g=w  then you will see there is a daily, weekly, monthly option.  I would like to pull the weekly into a dataframe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can downsample using the `asfreq` method:

```
sp = sp.asfreq('W-FRI', method='pad')
```

The `pad` method will propagate the last valid observation forward.

Using `resample` (as @tshauck has shown) is another possibility. 
Use `asfreq` if you want to guarantee that the values in your downsample are values found in the original data set. Use `resample` if you wish to aggregate groups of rows from the original data set (for example, by taking a mean). `reindex` might introduce NaN values if the original data set does not have a value on the date specified by the reindex -- though (as @behzad.nouri points out) you could use `method=pad` to propagate last observations here as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you check the latest [pandas source code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/commit/f88f15b60d4b50391b8a188cf05bbc4643d4f494) on github, you will see that interval param is included in the latest master branch. You can manually modify your local copy by overwriting the same data.py under your Site-Packages/pandas/io folder

Answer (score 2):

you can always reindex to your desired frequency:

```
sp.reindex( pd.date_range( start=sp.index.min( ),
                           end=sp.index.max( ),
                           freq='W-WED' ) )  # weekly, Wednesdays
```

**edit**: you may add `, method='ffill'` to forward fill `NaN` values.

As a suggestion, take Wednesdays because that tend to have least missing values. ( i.e. fewer NYSE holidays falls on Wednesday ). I think Yahoo weekly data gives the stock price each Monday, which is worst weekly frequency based on S&P data from 2000 onwards:

```
import pandas.io.data as web
sp = web.DataReader("^GSPC", "yahoo", start=dt.date( 2000, 1, 1 ) )

weekday = { 0:'MON', 1:'TUE', 2:'WED', 3:'THU', 4:'FRI' }
sp[ 'weekday' ] = list( map( weekday.get, sp.index.dayofweek ) )
sp.weekday.value_counts( )
```

output:

```
WED    722
TUE    717
THU    707
FRI    705
MON    659
```

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to mask on the day of week you want.

```
sp[sp.index.dayofweek == 0]
```

Another option would be to resample.

```
sp.resample('W', how='mean')
```

Answer (score 2):

That's how I convert daily to weekly price data:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

start = datetime.datetime(1972, 1, 3)
end = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 3)

stock_d = web.DataReader('^IXIC', 'yahoo', start, end)

def week_open(array_like):
    return array_like[0]

def week_close(array_like):
    return array_like[-1]

stock_w = stock_d.resample('W',
                    how={'Open': week_open, 
                         'High': 'max',
                         'Low': 'min',
                         'Close': week_close,
                         'Volume': 'sum'}, 
                    loffset=pd.offsets.timedelta(days=-6))

stock_w = stock_w[['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']]
```

more info:

https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html#yahoo-finance
https://gist.github.com/prithwi/339f87bf9c3c37bb3188